# Disqus not loading in Jekyll Blog

Tags: javascript, html, jekyll, disqus

I am unable to get Disqus working for my Jekyll Blog. I followed the instructions on the Disqus website.
I added comments to the post layout

```
---
layout: default
comments: true
---
<h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>
<p>{{ page.date | date_to_string }} - {{ page.author }}</p>

{{ content }}

{% include disqus.html %}
```

with disqus.html using the code generated by Disqus website

```
{% if page.comments %}
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
<script>

/**
*  RECOMMENDED CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT AND UNCOMMENT THE SECTION BELOW TO INSERT DYNAMIC VALUES FROM YOUR PLATFORM OR CMS.
*  LEARN WHY DEFINING THESE VARIABLES IS IMPORTANT: https://disqus.com/admin/universalcode/#configuration-variables*/

var disqus_config = function () {
this.page.url = {{ page.url }};  // Replace PAGE_URL with your page's canonical URL variable
this.page.identifier = {{ page.id }}; // Replace PAGE_IDENTIFIER with your page's unique identifier variable
};

(function() { // DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');
s.src = 'https://rohit-gupta-blog.disqus.com/embed.js';
s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
(d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
})();
</script>
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="https://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>

{% endif %}
```

Here is an example of a blog post on my website [post](https://rohitkumargupta.com/blog/2020/01/15/rohit-gupta-blog-launched). [Here](https://github.com/rohitgupta-physics/rohitgupta-physics.github.io) is my git hub repository if it is needed.

Comment: Maybe the `{% if page.comments %}` condition isn't working (it's not true). Try temporarily removing `{% if page.comments %}` and the associated `{% endif %}` to verify.

Comment: Still not working. However I can now see the script in the page source.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `page.url` and `page.url` should be strings, but they aren't in quotes. Here's the config that is rendered on your page:

```js
var disqus_config = function () {
  this.page.url = /blog/2020/01/15/rohit-gupta-blog-launched;
  this.page.identifier = /blog/2020/01/15/rohit-gupta-blog-launched;
};
```

This is likely what you want:

```js
var disqus_config = function () {
  this.page.url = 'https://rohitkumargupta.com/blog/2020/01/15/rohit-gupta-blog-launched';
  this.page.identifier = '/blog/2020/01/15/rohit-gupta-blog-launched';
};
```

**Full Updated disqus.html**

```html
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
<script>

/**
*  RECOMMENDED CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT AND UNCOMMENT THE SECTION BELOW TO INSERT DYNAMIC VALUES FROM YOUR PLATFORM OR CMS.
*  LEARN WHY DEFINING THESE VARIABLES IS IMPORTANT: https://disqus.com/admin/universalcode/#configuration-variables*/

var disqus_config = function () {
  this.page.url = 'https://rohitkumargupta.com{{ page.url }}';  // Replace PAGE_URL with your page's canonical URL variable
  this.page.identifier = '{{ page.id }}'; // Replace PAGE_IDENTIFIER with your page's unique identifier variable
};

(function() { // DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
  var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');
  s.src = 'https://rohit-gupta-blog.disqus.com/embed.js';
  s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
  (d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
})();
</script>
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="https://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. You solution 'worked', but I am getting a message 'We were unable to load disqus'.

Comment: Hey @RohitKumarGupta. I believe that Disqus is expecting the `page.url` property to be the full canonical URL for your post. Try adding the protocol and domain to the string. I've updated my answer.